# User (member) specific site menu or hierarchy

Tags: ee2, navigation

This is kind of an open ended question, but has any one had any luck with creating a "member specific" navigation tree? I've looked into structure, taxonomy, and nav-ee but none seem to have the granularity of permissions I would need.

What I'm trying to achieve is that a member can login and create a "micro site" that would allow the following:

The member **can**:

- create new pages or edit existing pages (created by the member)
- create/manage a single
  multi-tier menu which controls the order and hierarchy of the
  micro-site pages.

The member **cannot**:

- View/edit other micro sites
- Add or edit pages outside of their micro-site
- Alter any other site menus.

Ideally I'd like to manage this through some kind of jQuery-esque list that allows for nesting/re-ordering etc. I know this is a bit of a tall order. 0.o I'm willing to hack some stuff together if need be, but I was wondering if there was an existing solution somewhat close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Any one else put together something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Kara,
We built a site kind of similar to this a couple of years back for an organisation.

In that case we used Structure and then http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access to restrict access to the entries. It was a pretty manual process though and no way to really create a micro-site automatically, they initially had to be setup by a general master account.

I believe that Taxonomy will also allow you define a 'per tree' access for member groups.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the permission at the "member" level instead of the "member group" level. To your knowledge would restricting the access by entry-access cause users to not see these entries in structure or taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to need some custom modules to do this.  Structure is sort of designed for this sort of page structuring, but it doesn't work outside of the CP.

Also there is now way of automating the process without some custom extensions (eg: when creating the member, you want the default "root" page that all other pages descend from to be created automatically).

If you could get the the "root" page created, you could use Safe cracker to allow the member to create descendant pages once on that page.  You could have a relationship field that you set using a hidden input on the page.

The problem would come when you want to order them. You would need an "order" text field added to the channel and then use a jQuery order plugin that submits to Safecracker behind the scenes - which is tricky to get right.

All in all, there are no existing addons that would let you achieve this quickly since you will need to go down a custom addon route.

Also this could be seen to fall under EE's [restricted use licence](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/license.html) whereby you are not allowed to:

> Use the Software as the basis of a hosted blogging service, or to provide hosting services to others.

Worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Yeah we had to check out the licence use as well. In our scenario the main site was for a big organisation who had chapters with small sites. They weren't selling the service so seems it was OK.

Comment: I don't think the license would be an issue in this case as it is being used for "teacher sites" that are really just sub-sections of the primary site. The access restriction comes in that individual teachers should only be allowed to access the pages they've created.

Comment: I could build a front-end page that pulls in only the members current entries and sorts them... then saves out the menu as html... but I don't know where to save it... Yeah. I think this would pretty much needs to be a custom module. :)